# not applicable for the arguments (CursorAdapter)

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, search-suggestion

The method `setSuggestionsAdapter` of a `SearchView` gives me a strange Error:

I have a class `InformationAdapter` that extends `CursorAdapter`, but it says me that I cannot 
cast it to an `CursorAdapter`.

> The method setSuggestionsAdapter(CursorAdapter) in the type SearchView
>   is not applicable for the arguments (InformationAdapter)

```
      InformationAdapter suggestionsAdapter = new InformationAdapter(false, this, suggestions, CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
      searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have now figured out what the mistake was:

My `InformationAdapter` used to extend the `CursorAdapter` from the support.v4 Framework.
That did not work. Changing to `import android.widget.CursorAdapter;` solved the problem.